# Changing google language

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, language, redirection, geolocation

My question is simple: how can I change google language? When I visit `www.google.com` it writes response code `302 moved` and redirect me to `www.google.tk`. I've changed the language setting in chrome, I also changed language setting on my google plus account, but I am still being redirected.
I thought that chrome sends some information about my language, so I tried Mozilla, but I have still been redirected.
The last option I've tried is to get content of `www.google.com` from Node.js, but it still sends `302` response code and redirect me to other language site.
I also tried using proxy, but page is not rendered correctly and many functionalities doesn't work properly.
I realy do not want to read non-english words when I use google. Does google geolocate my IP every time I visit its page? Is there any way of changing language. It really annoys me.

Comment: Why downvote? Is my question out of scope? Did I wrote something wrong?

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that this is not about language selection, but CDN magic routing you to the best performing google site for your area  (as assumed by your source IP). you will notice that if you use a proxy/VPN system of some kind to access google from another countries IP ranges, it will  come up in that countries native/predominant language.

Comment: @FrankThomas. I'm just wondering why google doesn't allow users to manualy change language. I simply cannot find a way to browse google docs or google surveys or other google products in english (while there is a simple way to change language on youtube).

Comment: This is really a website redirect issue, not specifically a language one. google.com is presumed to be a US English site, but from foreign countries it seems to want to think for you (I hate that). Have you tried another English language Google site, like https://www.google.co.uk/ ?

Comment: [Here](/questions/398790/how-can-i-force-my-browser-to-search-google-in-english "How can I force my browser to search Google in English?") and [there](/questions/59118/how-do-you-make-googles-interface-always-be-in-your-chosen-language "How do you make Google's interface always be in your chosen language?") are the canonical versions of this question on superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to http://www.google.com/ncr to block the automatic redirecting.
<sub>[Source](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/873?hl=en)</sub>